# log4net write null to file unexpectedly

Tags: log4net

Does anybody encounter the error from log4net that many null are written with RollingFileAppender unexpectedly when the system gets hang?

The file log will be like below:

```
2014-06-05 11:40:45,993 [5156] INFO  myapp.test.Main getStatus
2014-06-05 11:40:45,995 [5156] INFO  myapp.test.Main getStatus
[NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL]2014-06-05 11:51:58,418 [2992] INFO  myapp.test.Main Start...
```

log4net Version: 1.2.10

Below is log4net.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
<file value="C:\Test\Log\log4net-log.txt" />
<appendToFile value="true" />
<rollingStyle value="Date" />
<datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />    
<staticLogFileName value="true" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
<conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger %message%newline" />
</layout>
</appender>
<appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender" >
<applicationName value="Test" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
<conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger %message%newline" />
</layout>
</appender>
<root>
<level value="DEBUG" />
<appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
</root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Please try to give some more information regarding the problem; what are you logging, what do you mean by system "gets hang", is it the whole box freezing or only your process; please add some info if you want some answers

Comment: Sorry about that, that's all information I can get from the file log. How can I get more debugging information from log4net?